# Стоит ли указывать модификатор доступа final для класса?

Tags: java, android

Сам модификатор говорит о том, что класс нельзя будет расширять. Но я думаю в плане оптимизации самого кода, если я точно знаю, что я не собираюсь наследоваться от класса `A`, то почему бы его не сделать `final` ...

Может это будет подсказка для копилятора при компиляции или при выполнении кода?

Comment: @metalurgus Насколько мне удалось вынести из лекций всяких ученых теоретиков Java, final нужно ставить везде, где он только уместен и что это сильно облегчает работу как компилятору при сборке, так и виртуальной машине при выполнении.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Модификатор `final` запрещает наследоваться от данного класса. С точки зрения оптимизации и производительности, это хорошая подсказка для `jvm`. При вызове методов у какого то класса, происходит поиск в классах наследниках, для определения - переопределен ли данный метод. Таким образом обеспечивается полиморфизм. Хотя, существует очень много оптимизаций и совсем  необязательно, что он будет каждый раз делать эти манипуляции. Если мы укажим `final`, то интерпретатор не будет ничего искать, точно зная, что этот метод не был переопределен.